# Best Practice to Maintain Matching Chromedriver+Chrome Versions for Selenium/Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a very simple Selenium/Ruby script, with the following key line excerpts:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
...
require 'selenium-webdriver'
...
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
...
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
...
driver.quit
```

Quite simply, it just uses the operating system's (Ubuntu Linux) default offerings for Chrome and Chromedriver.

Every now and then, the Chrome automatically updates, and the Chromedriver does not, causing the script to start failing when run:

```sh
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version XX
Current browser version is YY with binary path /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

It is trivial for me to manually update Chromedriver each time, but it is annoying.

What is the best practice way to automagically keep Chromedriver updated to match Chrome?

Comment: this is why the webdrivers gem was created. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally in Python we use `auto installer` please see [here](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/), which is basically that auto install `chromdriver` against appropriate chrome browser version. We have the same functionality in `Java-Selenium` bindings as well using `WebdriverManager`.

Since you are asking for solely in `ruby-Selenium bindings`, I could find one Github repo, Please see [here](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers).

**Run Selenium tests more easily with automatic installation and updates for all supported webdrivers.**

1. chromedriver
2. geckodriver
3. IEDriverServer
4. msedgedriver

Works on `macOS`, `Linux`, `Windows`, and `Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) v1` and `v2`. And do see the browser and OS specific notes at the bottom.

**Usage**

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0', require: false
```

In your project:

```
require 'webdrivers'
```

The drivers will now be automatically downloaded or updated when you launch a browser through Selenium.